# How to edit an AVI tag?

Tags: c#, tags, movieclip

How can I read and write the tags of an AVI file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [TagLib#](http://developer.novell.com/wiki/index.php/TagLib_Sharp) library, it's written entirely in .net and it's LGPLv2

Comment: thanks! very useful and interesting.. works with mp3, avi...
thanks!